# how to quickly add conditional block to line in vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I m using vim/NeoVim, and I wonder if there is a way to quickly surround a line with conditional if block.

for example, I want to turn

```
var b = 123;
```

into

```
if (a == null) {
  var b = 123
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the behavior should be? You surround a line with `if`, parentheses for the conditional statement, but have the parentheses be empty?  And end up with cursor inside the conditional parentheses?

Comment: What I mean is, I want to select an existing line and surround it with `if () {` before the line, and `}` after the line when I am done.

Currently I do it in an inefficient way, what I do is, I press shift O to jump to line above, then enter `if (...) {}`  (since I have auto-parenthesis plug-in, the `}` is automatically appended. I then have to remove `}` and jump to 2 lines down, to paste `}`'. The whole process just feels awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical method, as shown by Matt, would be, from normal mode and for a single line:

```
cc
if (a == null) {<CR>
<C-r>"
}
<Esc>
```

or, from normal mode and for an arbitrary motion:

```
c<motion>
if (a == null) {<CR>
<C-r>"
}
<Esc>
```

or, after a visual selection:

```
c
if (a == null) {<CR>
<C-r>"
}
<Esc>
```

Since you have an autoclosing plugin, it would probably look more like this:

```
c
if (a == null<Right> {<CR>
<C-r>"
<Esc>
```

You can't really hope for a more efficient manual method.

If that's something you do often, it might prove handy to automatize the process. This is typically done with a mapping, where the right-hand side is a macro, eg what you would actually type. Using the non-plugin macro above as a starting point, it would look like this:

```
xnoremap <F5> cif (a == null) {<CR><C-r>"}<Esc>
```

You might need to adjust the macro a little to account for your autoclosing plugin.

You can even be fancy and visually select the arguments in select mode, like in a snippet expansion plugin:

```
xnoremap <F5> cif (<C-o>m'a == null) {<CR><C-r>"}<Esc>``vi(<C-g>
```

[image: map]

See `:help i_ctrl-r`, `:help i_ctrl-o`, `:help m`, and `:help select-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

For example, delete current line, add "if" then put it back etc. Using Insert mode allows to set indents properly.

<kbd>cc</kbd>if (cond) {<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Control-R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>}<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I would use a macro.

1. Put your cursor on the line you want to do this to.
2. Use `q` in normal mode and any letter of your choosing to start recording a macro on that letter. For instance, we can store the macro in letter `a` by typing `qa`.
3. Then type what you need to type to get the conditional block. You could choose to end your macro by putting the cursor back inside the empty parentheses so that each time you create an if block, you can immediately write the conditional statement. To end recording the macro, press `q` again in normal mode.
4. Now to use your macro, just go to another line you want to surround in an if block and type `@` and the letter that's storing the macro. In my example, I would type `@a`. And this can be done for each individual line or you can apply the macro to lines that match a certain pattern by doing `:g/pattern/norm @a`.